# Bash script: hex

Tags: bash, hex

I'm trying to do the following:

```
ch='\x21'
line="\x21"
len=50
for i in `seq 1 $len`
do
    line+="$ch"
done
```

Instead of 50 '!' (hex code \x21) I get a list of 50 '\x21'. How can I do this in bash?

Comment: Do you want the total sum of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the man page, "Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially". Thus, adding `$''` to the mix may help:

```
% bash
bash-3.2$ ch=$'\x21'; echo $ch$ch$ch
!!!
bash-3.2$
```